# Minimal polynomial of the shift operator in $\mathbb{k}_{10}[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{k}$ be a field and denote by $\mathbb{k}_{10}[x]$ the vector space of all polynomials of $x$ of degree at most 10.

Define the shift operator $T:\mathbb{k}_{10}[x]\to \mathbb{k}_{10}[x]$ by equation $T(f(x))=f(x+1)$. Find the minimal polynomial of this operator.

**My approach:** Consider the standard basis of $\mathbb{k}_{10}[x]$ namely $\{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^{10}\}$. And if we write the matrix of this operator we will get $11\times 11$ matrix which is upper diagonal with $1$'s on the diagonal.

Then the characteristic polynomial of this operator will be $P(t)=(t-1)^{11}$. Since minimal polynomial $\mu(t)$ divides it then it should be of the form $(t-1)^k$, $0<k\leq 11$. I am trying to show that $k=11$ but cannot prove it rigorously.

Suppose $k<11$ then $\mu(t)=(t-1)^k$. Hence it means that the operator $(f-\text{id})^k$ is trivial operator. I was applying it to $x^k$ trying to get contradiction but no results.

Would be very grateful if anyone can show the solution!

Comment: $k_{10}[x]$ is not a field!

Comment: By "$\mathbb k_{10}[X]$ the field of all polynomials of $x$ of degree at most $10$" you mean the vector space of all polynomials of  $x$ of degree $\le10$, right?

Comment: @Bernard, yeah it was a typo! Thanks a lot for that. It is just a ring of polynomials

Comment: @kimchilover, yeah exactly!

Comment: So edit your question accordingly.  By the way, it is not a "ring of polynomials" either.

Comment: @kimchilover, yeah you're definitely right! since the product in this set is not binary operation!

Comment: Why downvote? It's a quite interesting question!

Comment: Isn't the claim false for prime characteristic less than 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

You can check the matrix is
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&\dots&1&\dots&1\\
0&1&2&3&\dots& k&\dots& 10 \\
0&0&1&3&\dots &\binom k2 &\dots&\binom{10}2 \\
\vdots & &&\vdots &\ddots &\vdots &&\vdots \\
0& 0&0&0&\dots&1&\dots&\binom{10}k\\
\vdots & &&\vdots & &\vdots &&\vdots \\
0&0&0&0&\dots&0&\dots&
\binom{10}9\\
0&0&0&0&\dots&0&\dots&1
\end{pmatrix}=I+N,$$
and show (by an easy finite induction) that each power $(T-I)^r=N^r$ has exactly its first $r$ columns which are null columns.

Comment: Hmm. It is a really nice idea! If $k<11$ and $(f-\text{id})^k$ is trivial operator then matrix of this operator  which is $(T-I)^k$ should be zero matrix but your reasoning shows that the first $k$ columns are zero and and the rest $11-k>0$ are nonzero(actually they are positive). Right?

Comment: I think so . There remains to find a good argument  (I mean, as short and convincing as possible) to show that at least one of the other columns is non-zero, but it shouldn't be too hard, as all coefficients are positive.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that $(T-I)^{10}$ is not the zero operator. Indeed, we have
$$(T-I)^{10} = \sum_{k=0}^{10} {10 \choose k} (-1)^{10-k}T^k.$$

Plugging in the polynomial $x^{10}$ yields

$$(T-I)^{10}x^{10} = \sum_{k=0}^{10} {10 \choose k} (-1)^{10-k}(x+k)^{10}$$
which has constant term equal to
$$\sum_{k=0}^{10} {10 \choose k} (-1)^{10-k}k^{10} = 10!$$

This can be calculated by hand, or by using [this identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1081134/144766). Therefore $(T-I)^{10}x^{10} \ne 0$ and hence $(T-I)^{10} \ne 0$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Work instead with the monomial basis of falling factorials $x^{\underline{n}}=x(x-1)\cdots (x -n+1)$, and let $\Delta=T-I $.

Then from the identity of formal power series $\mathbb{Q}[x][[t]]$
$$\Delta^m(1+t)^x = t^m(1+t)^x$$
one finds
$$\Delta^mx^{\underline{n}}=n^{\underline{m}}x^{\underline{n-m}}$$
so that by direct calculation, the minimal polynomial $m(\delta)$ of $\Delta$ is $\delta^p$ if the characteristic of the field of scalars is $p=2,3,5,7$, $\delta^{11}$ otherwise.

For in the characteristic $p$ cases given, $p|n^{\underline{p}}$ because $n^{\underline{p}}$ is a product of $p$ consecutive integers, but $n\equiv -1\pmod{p}\Rightarrow n^{\underline{p-1}}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ by Wilson's Lemma, so that $\Delta^p=0$ but $\Delta^{p-1}\neq 0$.

And in the other characteristics, we have $\Delta^{11}=0$ but $\Delta^{10}\neq 0$, since $p$ does not divide $n^{\underline{m}}$ for $m\leq n<p$.

Comment: How did you get these answers? Could you show more details?

Comment: Right now it is beyond of my knowledge. So it turns out that our answer is wrong?

Comment: Without the further assumption that 2,3,5, and 7 are invertible in $\mathbb{k}$, it's wrong.