# $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k} k^n = (-1)^n n!$ ?!

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, summation

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k} k^v
=
\begin{cases}
  0 & (v=0,1,\dots,n-1), \\
  (-1)^n n! & (v=n).
\end{cases}
$$

This formula appears in the book "*Introduction to Analysis*" (written by [Teiji Takagi](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%AB%98%E6%9C%A8%E8%B2%9E%E6%B2%BB)) ~ Chapter 2 "Differential Method" ~ Section 25 "Taylor's Formula" ~ "Additional Notes" (discussing the "difference" in differential calculus). [( Scanned image of that page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTjYj.png)

---

What I have tried:

$$
\newcommand{\cc}[2]{{\color{#1}#2}}
\newcommand{\cR}[1]{\cc{Red}#1}
\newcommand{\cO}[1]{\cc{Orange}#1}
\newcommand{\cY}[1]{\cc{Yellow}#1}
\newcommand{\cG}[1]{\cc{Green}#1}
\newcommand{\cB}[1]{\cc{Blue}#1}
\newcommand{\cI}[1]{\cc{Indigo}#1}
\newcommand{\cV}[1]{\cc{Violet}#1}
\begin{align*}
\text{LHS}
&=
  -n
  +\frac{n(n-1)}       {2\cdot1}       2^v
  -\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}  {3\cdot2\cdot1} 3^v
  +
  -\cdots
  +\frac{n(n-1)\cdots1}{n(n-1)\cdots1} n^v \\
&
\begin{array}{}
= -   n   \cR(            1                \\ &\kern-1.5em
  - (n-1) \cO(            2^{v-1}          \\ &&\kern-2.8em
  - (n-2) \cY( \dfrac    {3^{v-1}}{2!}     \\ &&&\kern-3em
  - (n-3) \cG( \dfrac    {4^{v-1}}{3!}     \\ &&&&\kern-3em
  - (n-4) \cB( \cdots                      \\ &&&&&\kern-2.2em
  -\cdots \cI( \cdots                      \\ &&&&&&\kern-2.2em
  -   2   \cV( \dfrac{(n-1)^{v-1}}{(n-2)!} \\ &&&&&&&\kern-5.6em
  -            \dfrac    {n^{v-1}}{(n-1)!}
          \cV)\cI)\cB)\cG)\cY)\cO)\cR)
\end{array}
\end{align*}
$$

I'm stuck here, please help me, thanks!

---

Side note: For alternating sequences, there is a [more advanced question](/q/1904656) that has been answered.

Comment: think about the Taylor expansion on $(1-e^x)^n$

Comment: @user8268 $(1-e^x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k}   \sum_{v=0}^\infty \dfrac{k^v x^v}{v!}$, then how to extract $k^v$?

Comment: $=(-x-x^2/2-\dots)^n=(-x)^n+\dots$

Comment: For the $v=n$ case, you have lots of ways to solve this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081134/how-to-compute-sumn-k-0-1k-binomnkkn?noredirect=1).

Comment: @user8268 Still don't know how to proceed, 

Comment: @ooo my previous comment means that the coefficient at $x^k$ for $k<n$ is $0$, and at $x^n$ it is $(-1)^n$ (for $k>n$ it is whatever is hidden in the $+\dots$ of the formula I wrote)

Comment: @user8268 Pardon my stupidity ...

(1) Let $v=n, x=1$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \dbinom{n}{k} \sum_{v=n}^n \dfrac{k^v x^v}{v!}
=
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \dbinom{n}{k} k^n\,\frac{1}{n!},$$
How is it possible to get the result directly? There are still many steps in the middle, right?!

(2) What about for $v>n$ (to $\infty$)? (since you used $(1-e^x)$, but the result doesn't contain the "imprint" that $e^x$ expands to infinity, which surprises me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is to solve the $\nu=0,n=0,1,2,3,\dots$ case. From binomial formula:
$$ (1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk x^k$$
So in particular, $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk (-1)^k=(1+(-1))^n = 0.$

The next step is to use a differentiation trick for sums. Observe that
$$Tf(x):= x\frac{d}{dx}f(x), \quad T^2 f:=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right),\quad \dots $$
satisfies for $\nu\ge 0$
$$ T^\nu x^k=k^\nu x^k.$$
Hence, the sum in question is solved if we can compute the value of
$$ T^\nu(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk k^\nu x^k$$
at $x=-1$.

Note that $T1=0$, $T(1+x)=x$, and generally if $n\ge 1$ then $$T(1+x)^n = n(1+x)^{n-1} x = n(1+x)^{n-1} (x+1-1) = n\Big((1+x)^{n} - (1+x)^{n-1}\Big)  $$
Note that if $\nu=1=n$, then the $(1+x)^{n-1}=1$ term is not zero even when $x=-1$. But all higher powers of $(1+x)$ at $x=-1$ are zero. If instead $\nu=1<n$, this lowest order term also evaluates to zero: $(1+(-1))^{n-1}=0$. This proves the result for $\nu = 1, n\ge 0$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk k (-1)^k = \begin{cases} 0 & n\neq 1 \\ -1 & n=1 \end{cases}$$
Observe the lowest order coefficients of $(1+x)$:
\begin{align}
T(1+x)^n &= \dots - n(1+x)^{n-1}\\
T^2(1+x)^n &= \dots + n(n-1)(1+x)^{n-2}\\
T^3(1+x)^n &= \dots - n(n-1)(n-2)(1+x)^{n-3}\\
\vdots \quad &\quad \vdots \qquad \vdots 
\end{align}
Inductively, we see that if we write
$$ T^\nu (1+x)^n$$
as a sum of powers of $(1+x)$, the lowest order term is $$(-1)^\nu n^{\underline \nu}(1+x)^{n-\nu},$$ where $n^{\underline 
\nu}=n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-\nu+1)$ is the falling power. In particular, $n^{\underline n}=n!$. If $\nu < n$, then this evaluates to $0$, like all the higher order terms. If $\nu=n$, then this evaluates to $(-1)^n n!$; this is exactly what we sought to prove.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136842/discussion-on-answer-by-calvin-khor-sum-k0n-1k-n-choose-k-kn-1).

Answer (score 0):

It seems Takagi is doing the backward finite difference, see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences). One can feel a bit uneasy about using the letter $\Delta$ for the difference step and for the operator, but it's analogous to the infinitesimals, so it should be fine after a while.

Main point: if $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ then $\Delta P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ the the leading coefficient of $\Delta P(x)$ is $n \times$ leading coefficient of $P(x)$.

Now, also check that

$$\Delta^n f(x) = \sum (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} f(x- k h)$$

Now, if $P(x)$ is of degree $<n$ then $\Delta^n P(x) \equiv 0$, while if $P(x)$ is of degree exactly $n$ then
$\Delta^n P(x) = n! \times $ leading coefficient of $P(x)$.

The expressions you have are $\Delta^n P(x)$ at the point $n$ for the polynomial $P(x) = x^{\nu}$ ( use also $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$), and $h=1$.

Check an example [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5B%20Sum%5B%20%28-1%29%5Ek%20Binomial%5B7%2C%20k%5D%20%28x-k%29%5Ea%2C%20%7Bk%2C0%2C7%7D%5D%2C%20%7Ba%2C1%2C7%7D%5D) ( $n=7$, $a$ is $\nu$).